# How can I update the conda python version when it's not available in any channel?

Tags: python, anaconda

I want to update my conda environment to python3.7.7. However

```
conda install python=3.7.7
```

results in

```
PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - python=3.7.7

Current channels:

  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/osx-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
```

I have the correct version installed locally:

```
$ /usr/local/bin/python3 --version
Python 3.7.7
```

So how can I get conda to use that?

Answer (score 2):

Given that python 3.7.7 was released on March 10 (6 days ago), I think it's simply a matter of it not having been packaged into a conda package yet. There is usually a delay between a release and it having been conda packaged and tested.
If you are willing, and have the time, you could help contributing to https://conda-forge.org/ 
nb: Often packages arrive a little earlier into conda-forge (although 3.7.7 is not yet there), and if that would be the case, you can add conda forge to your channel list

```
$ conda install python=3.7.7 -c conda-forge
```

Edit:
To see which packages are available, you can use

```
$ conda search python
```

or

```
$ conda search python -c conda-forge
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you can get conda to use that python version. Conda needs to have control over it in order to effectively manage it. Conda does not control that python file.

[You can try standard virtual environments](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html). This is similar to conda virtual environments, but you only need python. Recommended way: In your case you would navigate to the folder for your project (using `cd` in the terminal) and type: `/usr/local/bin/python3 -m venv venv`. You have just created a folder named venv (the second venv in that code) that will contain files needed for your virtual environment. To activate do: `source venv/bin/activate`. Now you can proceed to `pip install [package_names]` (not conda as we are not in a conda environment) packages you want. They will only install into this folder. See link  for more information.